# Getting crontab "permission denied" on Python script even though it has executable permissions

Tags: python, unix, cron

I have a python script set to go off every minute in my crontab file:

`*/1 * * * * ~/ticker.py`

I've set permissions of ticker.py with `chmod +x ticker.py` to make the file executable.

I am still getting `/bin/sh: /home/ec2-user/ticker.py: Permission denied` in my `/var/spool/mail/ec2-user` mail file.

I'm using an Amazon Linux EC2 instance. I appreciate any help with this. Thank you

Comment: Does your file have the `#!/bin/env python` shebang?

Comment: Just tried adding it. Still getting 'permission denied'.

Comment: @DYZ You mean `#!/usr/bin/env python`, yes?

Comment: Can  you run `~/ticker.py` on the command line?

Comment: Yes, that's the one I tried.

Comment: Yes, ticker.py runs just fine on the command line.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes.

Comment: Are you sure that you're looking at the crontab for the same account your interactive shell runs under? What does `ls -l ticker.py` say? Does `crontab -l` from your shell prompt show that entry? (Yes, I'm grasping at straws.)

Comment: Just found and posted the fix. Unsure why the shebang didn't work but just turning the cron entry into a python command fixed the issue. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the fix. Super simple but unsure why the `#!/usr/bin/env` shebang didn't fix it in the first place.

I replaced `*/1 * * * * ~/ticker.py` with `*/1 * * * * python ~/ticker.py`.

Thanks for the input.